# PlotNeuralNet plot interpretation

Tags: pytorch, visualization, pytorch-geometric

I am new to machine learning, I know how to build a simple neural network, but I don't know how to visualize my model accurately.

`PlotNeuralNet` is really an amazing LaTeX package, however, I don't quite understand the notations of the examples.

Taking this plot as an example:

[image: PlotNeuralNet Sample Plot]

If we look at convolution layer 1 (conv1), what do the two `64`s mean? What about `I`? To be specific, what does thicknesses of the layers mean? What about their sizes?

If I have a simple GCN regressor built by PyTorch Geometric like the following:

```py
    class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
        def __init__(self, hidden_size=32, num_params=3):
            super(GCN, self).__init__()
            self.conv1 = GCNConv(num_node_features, hidden_size)
            self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_size, hidden_size)
            self.conv3 = GCNConv(hidden_size, hidden_size)
            self.linear = Linear(hidden_size, num_params)

        def forward(self, x, edge_index, batch, return_embeddings=False):
            # 1. Obtain node embeddings
            x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
            x = x.relu()
            x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
            x = x.relu()
            x = self.conv3(x, edge_index)

            # Readout layer
            embeddings = global_mean_pool(x, batch)

            # Apply a final classifier
            x = F.dropout(embeddings, p=0.5, training=self.training)
            out = self.linear(x)

            if return_embeddings:
                return out, embeddings
            else:
                return out
```

Then how do I correspond the dimensions of inputs and outputs of each layer to the notations shown in the sample plot?

Comment: The 64 means the number of filters for those layers, and I means the input size (width/height) of the image. The thickness of the layers (roughly) relates to the number of filters for each of the layers, and the size very roughly (as you can see I/2 is not twice as small as I). indicates the size of the resulting array.

Comment: @Oxbowerce could you please elaborate a bit about the filters? What does filter mean in neural network?

Comment: Filters are the kernels that are convolved with the input array, see for example the following answer on stats.stackexchange on what this looks like.